# Django - creating an CRM like app makes me trouble

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like to create an app which will help generate offers. Let's assume I have two apps in Django project:

- offers which allows to: display offers list, creating the new ones
  and updating an existing offer.
- warehouse which allows to: display all goods added to warehouse, creating new ones, and updating existing goods.

During creating new offer I want to have a possibility to add some of the warehouse goods to the offer and set some additional parameters like: price, quantity and so on to print it on the offer. I want to achieve this using Bootstrap modal pop-up.

1. How should my models, and views files looks like to achieve this?
2. Should I use Many to Many relation ?

P.S. I am not sure if You even understand my doubts :D

Comment: Hi! Your question is too generic to answer. Give more details please.

Comment: Normally to display a creating offer view I am using a Django generic CreateView where I am choosing a model i.e. Offer. In urls.py I am setting a path to run this view. How can I display a pop-up with different model i.e. Warehouse without using a urls?